# How can I change the value of a variable in a struct?

Tags: c++, variables, struct

I'm currently doing my dissertation and a problem appeared that I cannot solve.

I need to change a single variable in a struct, but I can't find the definition of this variable, the code is not mine and it's massive so I don't know what to look for. The struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    double maxAperture; 
    double minAperture; 
    double A1; 
    double D3; 
} electric_gripper;
```

I need to change the value of the minAperture but I can't find how. There are a lot of constructors that initialize this struct and the function that is supposed to define the values if like this:

```
void Planner::setElectricGripper(ElectricGripper &egripper)
{
    this->egripper = egripper;
}
```

I've tried searching everywhere in the code for "egripper" but I can't find any values.
I wish I could show more code but like I said it's not created by me and it's massive so I can't show anything. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `egripper.minAperture = 12.5;`

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Presumably `ElectricGripper` is an alias for `electric_gripper`? Such as `typedef electric_gripper ElectricGripper;`? Note that `typedef struct { ... } <typename>;` is not needed in C++, it can (and should) be `struct <typename> { ... };` instead.

Comment: The syntax `inst->field` is used when dereferencing a pointer to a struct, and getting/setting the field. The syntax `inst.field` is used when getting/setting the field of a reference or value to a struct.

Comment: The code you posted seems (very few clues to assert it) a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: `egripper` is the name of a parameter. At the call site that name could be almost anything else. If you're looking for the origins of `egripper`, you are likely better off searching for calls to `setElectricGripper`.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: It;s a bit weird seeing the parameter being passed by non-const reference; since the parameter passed is never modified inside the function, you don't gain any benefits by not making the parameter const ref, but just unnecessarily prevent the function from being called with temporaries. Another weird thing here is not prefixing member variables with some specific prefix, but relying on the use of `this->`; choose a common prefix like `m_` and the body of the function becomes `m_egripper = egripper;` and also prevents issues in initializer lists of constructors...

Answer (score 0):

The structure should be defined like this:

```
 typedef struct electric_gripper
    {
        double maxAperture; 
        double minAperture; 
        double A1; 
        double D3; 
    } electric_gripper;
```

If you want to change maxAperture you can do as follows:

```
electric_gripper test;
test.maxAperture = 100;
```

Comment: In this example i was changed the value  of maxAperture before calling of this.egripper

Answer (score -2):

```
typedef struct
{
    double maxAperture;
    double minAperture;
    double A1;
    double D3;
} electric_gripper;

electric_gripper egripper;
void setElectricGripper(electric_gripper &egripper1)
{
    egripper1.maxAperture = 11.0;
    this.egripper = egripper1;
}
```

Comment: `this->` because `this` is a pointer. But forget that, because `setElectricGripper()` is not even a member function.

Comment: Don't explain your answer in comments. You can [edit] your answer to add information.